# Passing a variable to already implemented DLL functions

Tags: c#, rest, api, dll

I have a web api in c# which uses functions from custom DLL(my DLL so I have access to the code and can edit it).
the custom DLL code exposes functions and has access to a specific database.
is there a way to pass or read in another way a parameter to the DLL that overrides the default DB being used, I don't want to change the DLL functions and add the parameter in all of the function signatures? (so in **every** api call, I'll be able to pass the DB name and fetch the data dynamically)

Comment: Not without so much effort you might as well rewrite it... You could try decompiling it and modifying the methods and recompiling, but it's rarely that simple.

Comment: see my edit,it's my DLL so I have access to the DLL code and can make any changes that I want or need.

Comment: This would be really easy if the library was designed with dependency injection, or some kind of data provider, but without seeing the code it's impossible to tell you how to do this.

Comment: Does the DLL have a database connection string hardcoded somewhere?

Comment: @Jordoff part of the connection string (at least the one I want to change dynamically) configured in the web config file. I read the configuration file details and create the relevant connection on each access to the DB.

Comment: @RonBeyer Ron, unfortunately, there is no use in DI in this component, the simple way I thought of is to init the service constructor with the desired parameter and use it in the service after it was initialized.